# ¿Como pasar los datos acumulados en una variable en otra función en c++?

Tags: dev-c++

En una función ingreso datos, pero en otra funcion quiero hacer otra funcion con esos datos y no se como llamar a esos datos. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un poco del código que estas utilizado?

Comment: Hola Fernando, edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que no estás utilizando variables globales, por lo que puedes hacer dos cosas:

- Parámetros por copia
- Parámetros por referencia

Los parámetros por copia literalmente hacen una copia temporal de la variable que indicas, es decir, que al pasar una variable como parámetro de una función el valor de la variable es copiado y almacenado en una variable temporal de la función a la cual le estás pasando el parámetro.

Los parámetros por referencia crean una referencia a la variable que estás pasando como parámetro, es decir, que lo que sea que le hagas a la variable dentro de la función que la tiene como parámetro esa variable se verá afectada en las demás funciones donde esté esa variable.

**Copia** Aquí se pasan como copia

```
void funcion(int a, char b);
void hola(){
    int c = 4; char d = 'H';
    funcion(c, d);
}
```

**Referencia** Aquí se pasan como referencia

```
void funcion(int &a, char &b);
void hola(){
    int c = 4; char d = 'H';
    funcion(c, d);
}
```

Donde la primera línea de código de los dos ejemplos es el prototipo o declaración de tu función, y la función hola es un ejemplo de como utilizar la función al pasarle parámetros.